# Python NameError: name 'timeInMinutes' is not defined

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, calculator, nameerror

I am trying my best at learning python and although I have some experience, I seem to have a very basic problem;

I am using VS Code, along with the basic python "package" (the extensions it automatically installs for python) and I am trying to code a calculator that takes time in seconds and converts it to minutes + seconds, but as I am trying to run the very basic program, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'timeInMinutes' is not defined
```

my code:

```
timeInSeconds = 1823
timeInMinutes = timeInSeconds / 60
timeInRest = timeInSeconds % 60

print(f"Your time in minutes and seconds is {timeInMinutes}:{timeInRest}")
```

Edit:
I should specify: **I use python 3.9**

Should I downgrade to python 2?

Edit 2:
I am trying to run it, either using the green arrow in the top-right corner or using the shift+enter combo

Comment: This piece of code is working properly for me, isn't there anything more?

Comment: It doesn't seem like this error is coming from the code you attached. Also, which version of python do you use?

Comment: How are you running the code? With or without debugging?

Comment: you code works for me in the 'idle' / python 3.8
btw - probably you mean to use `timeInSeconds // 60`, not `timeInSeconds / 60`

Comment: Your above code runs with no problems... Also - *"Should I downgrade to python 2?"* - ***NO!***

Comment: The error suggests that something in your configuration is off. Notice that it says `File "<stdin>", line 1` rather than the actual file you are running... I would suggest to read some VSC documentation on how to run `py` files

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your debugger is configured for the green Play button, but SHIFT+ENTER runs only the lines you mark.

If you want to use the shortcut you need so select all of your code first.